# Theano: Shape of a tensor variable inside a function

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

Say I have this theano function, which defines a layer of a neural network:

```
def layer(W, x):
    b = np.array(np.ones(N))  # append 1 for intercept
    newx = T.concatenate([x, T.stack(b)], 0)
    return T.dot(W, newx)
```

I am concatenating ones (which is the b vector) to the end of the input data matrix x before passing it through W matrix. The problem is I need to specify a length for b. The data matrix has N columns, but say we do not know that beforehand.

I could not find how to properly do the theano equivalent of `size(x, 2)` in Matlab. I know `x` is a symbolic variable at this point, but I could not find how to find the shape of a tensor variable inside a function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [theano.tensor.shape](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.shape) to get the shape of the object in question, or, more directly, you can use [theano.tensor.ones_like](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.ones_like).

Comment: theano.tensor.shape() do not work.. (It returns Shape.0) - I think what I need to do is, somehow get the value, and then compute the shape. If x was a shared variable I could do that, but it is not..

Comment: And, could you give an example for theano.tensor.ones_like? Thanks!

Comment: theano.tensor.shape returns a tensor variable itself, so this is why it returns Shape.0. If you wanted to use this, you would do something like `b = T.ones(T.shape(x)[1])`.

Or, using ones_like, you could do `T.ones_like(x[0])`.

Comment: `ones_like` works! I couldn't get `ones` to work though.. Curious: What exactly is `x[0]`, I mean x is organized so that each column is a data item. When we say x[0] are we taking a row from x? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `x[0]` is indeed a row from `x`.

Comment: Needs an example to show how `theano.tensor.ones_like` would help.  @CemS. seems to have worked out the answer, but doesn't say what it is. Here's what I see: `ipdb> p T.ones_like(weights).
Elemwise{second,no_inplace}.0`. -- the `Elemwise` object is just as opaque as `Shape.0`

Answer (score 2):

Theano knows about the shape of an object using the "type" (see [Tensor basics](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html))

So x.type.dtype, x.type.ndim, x.type.broadcastable, give you a good set of information about the type and shape of a tensor variable.